# Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream in reading the second time in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mime-types, multipartform-data, readfile, memorystream

at first step I tried to read the contents into MultipartMemoryStreamProvider with the following code

```
 var multipartMemoryStreamProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
```

It solve my problem in getting the input File in memory.In this case I have access to other contents Key , but not value . 
I tried to get them with reading again the Contents into MultipartFormDataStreamProvider variable

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
```

Seems because I try to read the stream twice , it has the following error:

> Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not
>   complete

My first preference is to convert **MultipartMemoryStreamProvider** to **MultipartFormDataStreamProvider**

Is it possible to do that?